# Doorbell for a rectangular switch box

Tags: electrical, switch, junction-box, doorbell

I have a doorbell button that goes on a rectangular switch box that is outside my house. The rectangular switch box is inside concrete. Since the doorbell button is outside exposed to the weather, the plastic is brittle and is falling apart. The cover has gone a long time ago. Since the button itself is rectangular (a bit bigger than a light switch) I haven't been able to find anywhere. What is left on the doorbell says it was made in Costa Rica.

I am trying to find a replacement weatherproof (sun and rain) doorbell button and switch that will fit in a regular light switch box.

Comment: Can you post pictures?

Answer (score 2):

You can purchase a door bell button mounted in a cover plate that is designed to mount on a single gang electrical box. The one I located is sold on-line only through the [big orange box's web site.](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Viking-Door-Bell-Button-Panel-Bronze-VK-DB-40-BN/204398758)

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Build one.

[image: Blank faceplate]

## +

[image: Waterproof Metal Pushbutton with Blue LED Ring - 16mm Blue Momentary]

## = Awesome doorbell.

To actually make the light work you'd also have to put a [DC rectifier circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/516/10801) in the box since doorbells are typically AC.

---

Of course you can use any box cover that fits, and any weatherproof momentary push-button you can find that you like (that button was simply the first that came up for my search).